# FTP Authentication with SQL Database on IIS 8

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ftp, iis-8

I am trying to get my FTP site to use an SQL database table for authentication.  I found this [guide](http://techblog.edwardting.com/2010/07/21/creating-a-custom-database-driven-authentication-for-an-iis-7-ftp-site-using-visual-studio-c/).  And followed it almost to the letter, except I am using IIS 8 and Visual Studio 2010.  Now because the GAC is no longer put in C:\Windows\assembly I found my .dll in the new location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL.  After a lot of research I managed to find the properties for this (the Culture, Version, and Public Key Token that are required).  I added this as a custom provider.  Now it seems like everything is in place like it should be but when I log onto the ftp site it fails to log in with:

```
Response:   530 User cannot log in.
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I have been doing some trouble shooting and it doesn't look like the .dll is even being referenced.  I set it to always return true so that it would grant anyone with any password access, and received the same error.  I have been looking all over the place but all I can find is stuff about IIS 7 and things where the GAC is located in the old location. The FTP site was working fine, I was able to connect to it, with the basic authentication that is build in to IIS so I am pretty sure the site isn't the problem.

So my question is where do I go from here?  Is IIS 8 not looking in the new GAC location for my .dll?  Is this why it seems like the code isn't being run at all?  Or am I missing something that is obvious that will make me feel like an idiot when it gets answered?

I am stuck so even pointing me in a new direction would be helpful at this point.

Comment: The article you are referring to references `IIS7` are you sure that it will work the same with `IIS8` also can you show all relevant code that pertains to the current issue at hand..?

Comment: My code is exactly the code of the article with the exception of my connection string being different and table name being different in the SQL statement.  I didn't change anything else.  I am not sure it will work for IIS8 at all.  This was just the best example for what I was trying to do.  I am very new at IIS so I am learning as I go here.

Answer (score 0):

This happens all the time to me, I ask a question and then a short time later I stumble on the answer myself.  I made a rookie mistake here.  I found something that told me to connect to the ftp site through command prompt using FTP localhost.  Once there I saw the error that was really happening.  As it turns out the entire problem was with the SQL Server permissions for the NT Authority\SYSTEM user.  I went into the servers security->users then inthe NT Authority\SYSTEM properties.  In the User Mapping I checked the box for my database and the database role memberships in the bottom box.  I was immediately able to connect though both command prompt and through Filezilla.  Sorry I wasted anyone's time with this one, but hopefully this helps someone else out along the way.